# How to create java json dto for array or lists (non item name)?

Tags: java, json, spring, dto

I try to read from controller input json

When I uses name in node, everything is okey

There is json

```
{
    "itemList": [
        {
            "name": "Alex",
            "surname": "Ivanov",
            "age": "25"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daria",
            "surname": "Ivanova",
            "age": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

there is **itemList** in root of json

And I can catch it by this classes

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class UserController {
    @Post
    public ResponseEntity add(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
    //todo check breack point hear
        return new ResponseEntity<UserDto>(user, null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and model

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
    public List<UserItem> itemList;
}


@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserItem implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;
}
```

But, I need in really, I need to parse json like this:

Just items in objects without name

```
{
    [
        {
            "name": "Alex",
            "surname": "Ivanov",
            "age": "25"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daria",
            "surname": "Ivanova",
            "age": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to make it?

Comment: Is this json format valid ? or you forgot to remove outer curly braces ?

Comment: Use this `@RequestBody List<UserItem> itemList` if you want without list name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a malformed JSON object. The array inside doesn't have any key.

```
{
    [
        {
            "name": "Alex",
            "surname": "Ivanov",
            "age": "25"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daria",
            "surname": "Ivanova",
            "age": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think what you're looking for is a JSON array:

```
    [
        {
            "name": "Alex",
            "surname": "Ivanov",
            "age": "25"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daria",
            "surname": "Ivanova",
            "age": "23"
        }
    ]
```

To parse this JSON array, just modify your Controller to accept a list of `UserItem`:

```
@RequestBody List<UserItem> users
```